# How can I make this JavaScript work in a parent directory?

Tags: javascript, html, json, xmlhttprequest, jsonp

I have this script and a [test html page](http://pastebin.com/FKufgTdr).

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); //Request the data
        xhr.open('POST','http://gaben.capyspool.co.uk/gabencoin/public/index.php?page=api&action=getpoolstatus&api_key=72f3fd60d9a536215a6f6f92938592a60f919586635d7d0dedcf6a394888c435',true);
        xhr.send();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4) { //When it's ready
            var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText); //Parse the data
            document.getElementById('output').textContent = data.getpoolstatus.data.hashrate; //And here it is!
        }
       }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This script basically gets a value from a JSON file, accessed by URL and then represents it in a div tag with the id of 'output'. It is working as expected, [as seen here](http://gaben.capyspool.co.uk/gabencoin/test.html) (it returns the value of 0 or greater, which is correct for the time of posting). However when I place the exact same script in the directory /home, the script fails to work and gives me this error:

```
    XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://gaben.capyspool.co.uk/gabencoin/public/index.php?page=api&action=get…s&api_key=72f3fd60d9a536215a6f6f92938592a60f919586635d7d0dedcf6a394888c435. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://capyspool.co.uk' is therefore not allowed access.
```

You can see for yourself here: www.capyspool.co.uk/home/test.html (can't post more than 2 links). The location of the JSON file is in a subdirectory named 'gabencoin'. I am guessing that the script thinks that 'gabencoin' is an entirely different website. The file is hosted on the same server and domain, how can I get it so that I can load the value into the directory '/home'?
Guessing I will have to use JSONP, however, I have close to know experience with JavaScript and XML.

Comment: As long as domain, protocol and port match, this shouldn't be an issue. Try not using an absolute URL.

Comment: So would I refer to the JSON file as this? ../gabencoin/public/index.php?page=api&action=getpoolstatus&api_key=72f3fd60d9a536215a6f6f92938592a60f919586635d7d0dedcf6a394888c435

Comment: I don't know, try it and see? Why do you need an api key to get your own files ?

Comment: Yes thanks, that has worked!

Comment: Umm, http://gaben.capyspool.co.uk/home/test.html works for me as well.

Comment: Yes that is because I updated the script.